# Calculus existence and uniqueness of root.

Tags: calculus

Let $f:R\rightarrow R$ be a twice differentiable function such that $f(0) = 1$, $f'(x)<0$, and $f''(x)<0$ for all $x > 0$.
Prove that there exists a unique zero on $(0,\inf )$.

Is it sufficient to use concavity test and decreasing test to show that the likely graph would intersect the $x$-axis only once?

Answer (score 0):

well,

1) $f'(x) <0$ for $x>0$ tells you that $f$ is decreasing on the interval $(0,\infty)$. So $f$ is approaching the $x$-axis from above since $f(0)=1$

2) $f''(x)<0$ for $x>0$ tells you that $f$ is concave down, which implies the function will cross the axis.If $f''(x)>0$ then $f$ may approach but never cross the $x$-axis. For example consider $f(x)=e^{-x}$.

Because $f'(x)<0$ and $f''(x)<0$ for all $x>0$, the function will only cross the $x$-axis once, i.e. the root is unique. If $f$ were to cross again, there would need to be a change in concavity and a subset of $(0,\infty)$ in which $f$ is increasing.